# Android options menu top and bottom margin

Tags: android

I'm using a custom toolbar that is built this way:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/deepDarkVioletToolbar">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/defaultMargin"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/logo" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

It's usage:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".views.activities.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/default_toolbar" />

    <!-- other views go here -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm trying to add options menu to my application, so in order to do that I added this method to my activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    ((Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar)).inflateMenu(R.menu.main_menu);

    return true;
}
```

And my `main_menu` layout:

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/appMenu"
        android:title="menu"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.Widget.ImageButton"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_bg"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:checkable="false">

        <item android:title="Your orders" />
        <item android:title="Log out" />

    </item>

</menu>
```

The problem is that the options menu has some margins (paddings?) - top and bottom. You can take a look at this screenshot:

[image]

I have three questions (of which the first is the most important):

1. How do I get rid of those margins?
2. `android:icon` on menu item doesn't have any effect, so how do I put an icon there? If that's not possible then:
3. How to change color of those three dots?

Answer (score 0):

For icon color change use this

```
MenuItem find = menu.findItem(R.id.find_icon);
Drawable drawable = menuItem.getIcon();
if (drawable != null) {
     drawable.mutate();
     drawable.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
}
```